# How to model this probability over a discrete set?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume a discrete set $A=(1,2,\cdots,N)$.
I would like to model the following random phenomenon. Subsets of this set occurr at random with the following characteristics:

- Each element $i\in A$ has a probability $p_i$ of occurring in a subset
- The probability that the empty set occurs is zero.

So, for example, I can get realizations $(1,4,9)$, $(3,2)$, $(1,5)$ but I am sure at least one element will be in the materialized set.

Is there any known probability distribution that models this?

Comment: Your two characteristics together imply that the elements appearance are not independent of one another... at which point it will depend on the specific $p_i$'s if it is possible or not.  For extreme example, if your set were $\{1,2\}$ and $p_1=p_2=0.25$ this is impossible.

Comment: *since* they are not independent of one another, you will have to be more specific about in what way they are dependent on one another at which point your problem is underspecified.

Comment: hmmm... it cannot be the case that each element appears in the subset with probability $p$ AND the emptyset have probability $0$? If each element appears in the subset with probability $p$, then the probability of the emptyset must be $p^{N-k}$?

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy false.  You can have for instance the set being $\{1,2\}$ and each occurs with probability $p=0.5$.  It would just imply that $\Pr(\{1\})=\Pr(\{2\})=0.5$ and that $\Pr(\emptyset)=\Pr(\{1,2\})=0$.  In this extreme example you have the dependence of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are such that they are effectively complementary events.  With two elements in the set it is easy enough to work out how they must depend on one another, but with three or more there is a lot of freedom and the problem becomes underspecified. It is true that you can't have them be independent though, as said earlier

Comment: Based on these comments, I guess the probabilty of the empty set is $\Pi_{i=1}^N(1-p_i)$. Hence, the empty set has probability zero if and only if at least one elements has probability $p_i=1$.